# Infragistics xamGrid for Silverlight: How do I apply conditional formatting for summary row?

Tags: .net, formatting, silverlight-5.0, infragistics, xamgrid

I have a `TextColumn` in xamGrid which has summary enabled. What i want to do is display the sum in red if it is negative. This is how the column is defined:

```
<igGrid:TextColumn Key="Col1" HeaderText="Col1" 
 ValueConverter="{StaticResource NumberFormatter}"  ValueConverterParameter="#,##0" >
     <igGrid:TextColumn.ConditionalFormatCollection>
       <igGrid:LessThanConditionalFormatRule Value="0.00" StyleToApply="{StaticResource RedBrush}"/>
     </igGrid:TextColumn.ConditionalFormatCollection>
     <igGrid:TextColumn.SummaryColumnSettings>
       <igGrid:SummaryColumnSettings>
         <igGrid:SummaryColumnSettings.SummaryOperands>
           <igGrid:SumSummaryOperand IsApplied="True" FormatString="{}{0:N}"/>
           <igGrid:MaximumSummaryOperand FormatString="{}{0:N}"/>
           <igGrid:MinimumSummaryOperand FormatString="{}{0:N}"/>
         </igGrid:SummaryColumnSettings.SummaryOperands>
       </igGrid:SummaryColumnSettings>
     </igGrid:TextColumn.SummaryColumnSettings>
</igGrid:TextColumn>
```

How do i specify that the conditional formatting should be used not only for the column cells but also the summary cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the default Style for the SummaryRowCellControl and use a Converter to change the foreground based on the value of the summary.

In the Infragsaitics forums a similar question is discussed. You can see the sample attached [there](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/68341/346162.aspx)